# Getting JSON data into HashMap

Tags: android, arrays, json, hashmap

I get data from json like : "B11,B12,B22,F11,F22,F1,F2,F3"

then I have 50 icon in on layout , when I get data like " B11,B12,B22,F11,F22,F1,F2,F3 "

I hope 8 icons are VISIBLE , and 42 icons are INVISIBLE.

All I think is use HashMap , but actually , I really don't know how to do ?

This photo have 49 circles , every circles is ImageView.

49 circles is INVISIBLE if not get any data.

front photo have 27 cycles , back photo have 22 cycles.

B11 is local in right flank , F3 is local in right shoulder.

Those circles visible/invisible based on the json data I get.

[image]

my xml file :

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/pv_icon"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/view_pain_level"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_pain_position"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:src="@mipmap/pain_position" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/body_f1"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/body_height"
        android:layout_marginLeft="110dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/body_width"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_circle_black_2dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/body_b1"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/body_height"
        android:layout_marginLeft="266dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/body_width"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_circle_black_2dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/body_f2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/body_f1"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/body_height"
        android:layout_marginLeft="110dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/body_width"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_circle_black_2dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/body_b2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/body_b1"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/body_height"
        android:layout_marginLeft="266dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/body_width"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_circle_black_2dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/body_f3"
        android:layout_below="@+id/body_f2"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/body_height"
        android:layout_marginLeft="84dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/body_width"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_circle_black_2dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/body_f4"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/body_f3"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/body_height"
        android:layout_marginLeft="44dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/body_f3"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/body_width"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_circle_black_2dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/body_b3"
        android:layout_below="@+id/body_b2"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/body_height"
        android:layout_marginLeft="240dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/body_width"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_circle_black_2dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/body_b4"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/body_b3"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/body_height"
        android:layout_marginLeft="44dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/body_b3"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/body_width"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_circle_black_2dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/body_f5"
        android:layout_below="@+id/body_f2"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/body_height"
        android:layout_marginLeft="110dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/body_width"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_circle_black_2dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/body_f11"
        android:layout_below="@+id/body_f5"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/body_height"
        android:layout_marginLeft="110dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/body_width"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_circle_black_2dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/body_f15"
        android:layout_below="@+id/body_f11"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/body_height"
        android:layout_marginLeft="110dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/body_width"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_circle_black_2dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/body_f6"
        android:layout_below="@+id/body_f3"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/body_height"
        android:layout_marginLeft="80dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/body_width"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_circle_black_2dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/body_f9"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/body_f6"
        android:layout_below="@+id/body_f3"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/body_height"
        android:layout_marginLeft="9dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/body_f6"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/body_width"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_circle_black_2dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/body_f8"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/body_f9"
        android:layout_below="@+id/body_f5"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/body_height"
        android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/body_f9"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/body_width"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_circle_black_2dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/body_f7"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/body_f8"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/body_height"
        android:layout_marginLeft="9dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/body_f8"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/body_width"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_circle_black_2dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/body_f26"
        android:layout_below="@+id/body_f15"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/body_height"
        android:layout_marginLeft="96dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/body_width"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_circle_black_2dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/body_f27"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/body_f26"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/body_height"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/body_f26"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/body_width"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_circle_black_2dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/body_f10"
        android:layout_below="@+id/body_f6"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/body_height"
        android:layout_marginLeft="75dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/body_width"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_circle_black_2dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/body_f12"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/body_f10"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/body_height"
        android:layout_marginLeft="28dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/body_f11"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/body_width"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_circle_black_2dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/body_f13"
        android:layout_below="@+id/body_f10"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/body_height"
        android:layout_marginLeft="70dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/body_height"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_circle_black_2dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/body_f14"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/body_f13"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/body_height"
        android:layout_marginLeft="72dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/body_f13"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/body_width"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_circle_black_2dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/body_f16"
        android:layout_below="@+id/body_f13"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/body_height"
        android:layout_marginLeft="65dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/body_width"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_circle_black_2dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/body_f17"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/body_f16"
        android:layout_below="@+id/body_f14"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/body_height"
        android:layout_marginLeft="22dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/body_f27"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/body_width"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_circle_black_2dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/body_f18"
        android:layout_below="@+id/body_f26"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/body_height"
        android:layout_marginLeft="96dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/body_width"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_circle_black_2dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/body_f19"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/body_f18"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/body_height"
        android:layout_marginLeft="19dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/body_f18"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/body_width"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_circle_black_2dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/body_f20"
        android:layout_below="@+id/body_f18"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/body_height"
        android:layout_marginLeft="96dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/body_width"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_circle_black_2dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/body_f21"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/body_f20"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/body_height"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/body_f20"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/body_width"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_circle_black_2dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/body_f22"
        android:layout_below="@+id/body_f20"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/body_height"
        android:layout_marginLeft="96dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/body_width"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_circle_black_2dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/body_f23"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/body_f22"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/body_height"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/body_f22"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/body_width"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_circle_black_2dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/body_f24"
        android:layout_below="@+id/body_f22"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/body_height"
        android:layout_marginLeft="96dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/body_width"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_circle_black_2dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/body_f25"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/body_f24"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/body_height"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/body_f24"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/body_width"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_circle_black_2dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/body_b5"
        android:layout_below="@+id/body_b3"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/body_height"
        android:layout_marginLeft="235dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/body_width"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_circle_black_2dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/body_b6"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/body_b5"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/body_height"
        android:layout_marginLeft="14dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/body_b5"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/body_width"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_circle_black_2dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/body_b7"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/body_b6"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/body_height"
        android:layout_marginLeft="9dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/body_b6"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/body_width"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_circle_black_2dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/body_b8"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/body_b7"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/body_height"
        android:layout_marginLeft="13dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/body_b7"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/body_width"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_circle_black_2dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/body_b9"
        android:layout_below="@+id/body_b5"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/body_height"
        android:layout_marginLeft="225dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/body_width"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_circle_black_2dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/body_b10"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/body_b9"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/body_height"
        android:layout_marginLeft="23dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/body_b9"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/body_width"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_circle_black_2dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/body_b11"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/body_b10"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/body_height"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/body_b10"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/body_width"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_circle_black_2dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/body_b12"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/body_b11"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/body_height"
        android:layout_marginLeft="21dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/body_b11"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/body_width"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_circle_black_2dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/body_b13"
        android:layout_below="@+id/body_b9"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/body_height"
        android:layout_marginLeft="223dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/body_width"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_circle_black_2dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/body_b14"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/body_b13"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/body_height"
        android:layout_marginLeft="22dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/body_b13"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/body_width"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_circle_black_2dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/body_b15"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/body_b14"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/body_height"
        android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/body_b14"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/body_width"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_circle_black_2dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/body_b16"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/body_b15"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/body_height"
        android:layout_marginLeft="22dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/body_b15"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/body_width"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_circle_black_2dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/body_b17"
        android:layout_below="@+id/body_b14"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/body_height"
        android:layout_marginLeft="253dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="29dp"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/body_width"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_circle_black_2dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/body_b18"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/body_b17"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/body_height"
        android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/body_b17"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/body_width"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_circle_black_2dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/body_b19"
        android:layout_below="@+id/body_b17"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/body_height"
        android:layout_marginLeft="252dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="57dp"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/body_width"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_circle_black_2dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/body_b20"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/body_b19"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/body_height"
        android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/body_b19"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/body_width"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_circle_black_2dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/body_b21"
        android:layout_below="@+id/body_b19"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/body_height"
        android:layout_marginLeft="252dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="34dp"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/body_width"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_circle_black_2dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/body_b22"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/body_b21"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/body_height"
        android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/body_b21"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/body_width"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_circle_black_2dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: it's not clear, what exactly you want.

Comment: which points do "B11,B12,B22,F11,F22,F1,F2,F3" represent? more specifically which point in figure you understand by B11,B12.. etc ?

Comment: @some user 
Front phone have 27 circle's , B11 is number 11. it's local in right flank. I get data not only B11 , but also have other nember , all I get data is need to show in Front phone.

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, what you want is make those circles visible/invisible based on the ```json``` data you get?

Is that correct?

Comment: @some user
YES.

Comment: post codes where you're handling those ```json``` and ```imageview```s

Comment: how you're getting the data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After understanding your question hardly,

What you want to do is set visibility of some `ImageView`s to `VISIBLE` or `INVISIBLE` based on some data which I assume you got in `JSON` or any format. 
One way to achieve this is: first we get our data and manually set the `id`s of `ImageView`s in your `activity_*.xml` file.

Then dynamically update visibility accordingly.

In your view:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/pv_icon"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/view_pain_level"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/B11"  <-- Notice here
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:src="@mipmap/pain_position" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/B12" <-- Notice here
        android:layout_height="@dimen/body_height"
        android:layout_marginLeft="110dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/body_width"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_circle_black_2dp" />


       .
       .
       .

</RelativeLayout>
```

then in your `Activity`:

```
void setImageViews() {
    String data = getFromSomeComplicatedSource();
    String[] ids = data.split(",");

    for (String imageViewId : ids) {
        int resID = getResources().getIdentifier(imageViewId, "id", getPackageName()); // this will give R.id.ids[i]

        ImageView imageView = findViewById(resID);
        if (imageView != null) {
            imageView.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
            imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }
}

private String getFromSomeComplicatedSource() {
    // after getting data, convert it to String
    String data = "B11,B12,B22,F11,F22,F1,F2,F3";

    return data;
}
```

This way you achieve what you want.

Answer (score 0):

This is common question that we could only give advice about it.

Just create the xml view. After you can save api service variables in your class and decide which points are visible and which are not.

Good luck!